# Run programs in compatibility mode

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-gnome, compatibility

I want to know if there exist such a program that allows me to run a application native to Ubuntu with backwards compatibility, like in Windows.

Comment: What do you mean by "backwards compatibility" in Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you have any specific application in mind that used to run on older Ubuntu releases but is no longer working nowadays?

Comment: @ByteCommander I want to run steam in compatibility for Ubuntu 15.10 since I am experiencing issues with it ever since I upgraded to 16.04.

Comment: @Pilot6 You can run programs in Windows in what is called compatibility mode. Essentially run a program like it would on Windows XP when you have Windows 7 installed.

Comment: Graphics issues? What graphics card and drivers do you use? There were major changes in AMD support... But (although as general question this is totally okay) I think for your specific Steam issue you should (additionally) ask a separate question.

Comment: @ByteCommander I am using an Intel Ivy Bridge graphics card. Steam ran fine Under 15.10, however now games and software I have on it simply refuse to launch after the "preparing to launch NAME_HERE" window goes away. Thanks for the advice. After I get some more information will post in a specific question for this issue.